Java cannot find main class despite it being specified in project settings and manifest
In Netbeans 14, I created a new project. The IDE created it with the main class automatically populated. Once built, the JAR does not run, be it in Linux or Windows.
Package name:   com.Myself.MyProjectJ
Main class name: MyProjectJ
Properties->Run->Main class:    com.Myself.MyProjectJ

Contents of MyProjectJ.jar\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF:

Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.10.8
Created-By: 17.0.4+11-LTS-179 (Oracle Corporation)
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
Main-Class: com.Myself.MyProjectJ.MyProjectJ

Command line:
$java MyProjectJ.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class MyProjectJ.jar
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MyProjectJ.jar

$java -classpath MyProjectJ.jar com.Myself.MyProjectJ.MyProjectJ
No errors

What more can I do to allow Java to run the JAR w/o having to specify class path on the command line?

Hint from the error message: "Could not find or load main class MyProjectJ.jar" - why is it trying to find a class named "MyProjectJ.jar" ?! BTW - a bit confusing "Properties->Run->Main class:    com.Myself.MyProjectJ" and "Main-Class: com.Myself.MyProjectJ.MyProjectJ" - shouldn't it be the same main class?! And by convention, package names all lowercase

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928. Reason #1 example #7, and "Alternative syntaxes for java".

The correct commandline is java -jar MyProjectJ.jar. The -jar part is mandatory. There is no way to make java foo.x work where foo.x is a filename, unless it is a java app that fits into a single source file, i.e. a teensy tiny app.

BTW: Java 22 now also offers Launch Multi-File Source-Code Programs


What more can I do to allow Java to run the JAR w/o having to specify class path on the command line?

Simple.  Include the -jar option:
$ java -jar MyProjectJ.jar

The -jar is not specifying a classpath.  It is saying "treat this as an executable JAR file".  It will work with all mainstream Java implementations on all supported OS platforms.
Note: when you use the -jar option, you the JAR itself specifies the classpath.  A -cp or --classpath option on the java command line, and any CLASSPATH environment variable will be (silently) ignored.
AFAIK, there isn't a way to get java to treat a JAR file as executable without using the -jar option.  But there's nothing stopping you1 from creating a generic alias or script to do this.
See also:

What does "Could not find or load main class" mean?


1 - I'm not recommending this.  A better idea is to write application specific wrappers.

Java does not know that a JAR is a JAR without me telling it that?

@BusterZo - I don't want to argue with you.  Please read the official manual ... for whatever version of Java you are using.
